# Is it possible to distinguish HTTP requests made via 3G from other requests

Tags: ios, http

Specifically, when an http server receives a request from an iPhone, is there *any* way to determine with any certainty what kind of Internet connection the phone has?

If there's no way to determine this with certainty, are there any good heuristics?

Comment: That is a really good question. I doubt HTTP provides anything, but you may be able to look at the transport layer.

Comment: Can I ask what you *really* want to answer?  Other than throttling data to try to reduce potential data charges for a user, I can't think of any reason why you would want to know this particular information.  Maybe you really want to know about latency, connection quality, etc.?

Comment: I don't have an immediate need right now, but you already nailed the reason: to try to reduce potential data charges for a user. An app shipped with a couple of bugs, and one of the bugs could be accounted for at the server, but it would force the client to use a *lot* more data.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for digging out that corpse, but actually I just thought about the very same problem.
The point is: there is no way to detect that *directly*.

Altough, I came up with a approach, which sadly needs some preparation:
You need to get the hostname for the IP the request was made from.

For example, when I make a request to my webserver over with my phone over 3G network and resolve the request IP to the request hostname, I get this:

```
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.web.vodafone.de
```

So you would need to collect (or find on the internet) a list of mobile web provider hostnames.
With this approach, you can't exactly tell which kind of connection a user is using, but at least, you can distinguish between WiFi and mobile networks.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the iOS application, you should be able to set a custom header, say `X-iOS-ConnectionType`. If you are receiving a request from Mobile Safari, I would doubt you'd get anything, though you might try pinging the source IP address and check the transfer rate.

I should add that as with progressive enhancement and adaptive design, you are probably better served by detecting throughput rather than 3G/WiFi. While you are likely to get better throughput on WiFi, I've found several instances where 3G was much faster.

(Note that I have never looked at mobile traffic, and the source IP may not be a good indicator for client transfer rates.)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I'm looking for a mechanism that wouldn't require modifying the iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class to determine the internet connection and then include that in your HTTP request, e.g. as a parameter or custom HTTP header as Ryan Riley suggests.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go. The reachability class let you know if you are using wifi or not(then, its 3G)